# multiple submit buttons asp.net mvc 5 not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I followed the routine suggested in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework) the one with two buttons with the same name.

I have two submit buttons in my View.

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="SaveAndAddMore" name="command" class="btn btn-default" />
            <input type="submit" value="SaveAndContinue" name="command" class="btn" />

        </div>
    </div>
```

In the controller, I am checking (or atleast want to check) the value of command passed

```
     [HttpPost]
     [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
     public ActionResult CreateEducation([Bind(Include = "DegreeEarned,Description,Institution,AcquiredDate,EducationStartDate,EducationEndDate,Department,InstitutionAddress,ReferenceName,ReferencePhoneNumber,ReferenceEmail")] Education ed, Command command)
     {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var user = userManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            user.ExpertInfo.Educations.Add(ed);
            db.SaveChanges();
            if (command == Command.SaveAndAddMore)
                return RedirectToAction("CreateEducation");
            else
                return RedirectToAction("CreateWorkExperience");
        }

        return View(ed);
    }
```

however / when I click on `SaveAndAddMore` button (the one with the default class), my controller method is invoked correctly with the correct command value and all is well.
until I click on `SaveAndContinue`. On this instance, the controller is not passing any value for command.

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'command' of non-nullable type 'xxx.Models.Command' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult CreateEducation(Experts.Models.Education,
>   Experts.Models.Command)' in
>   'xxx.Areas.Expert.Controllers.ExpertInfoesController'. An
>   optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be
>   declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

The Command type is an enum

```
public enum Command { SaveAndAddMore, SaveAndNext, Save, Delete }
```

where have I gone wrong?

Comment: what is the Command class in the parameters?

Comment: have you tried with `string command` parameter in controller?

Comment: @AmrElgarhy: please see my edit, just an enum

Comment: @Amogh: no I havent, but would it make a difference, given that the default button (SaveAndAddMore) works. I am going to try anyway.

Comment: @Krishna, As you said for SaveAndAddMore is working try changing value of second button to  `SaveAndNext` as your Enum does not contain `SaveAndContinue`

Comment: Hi Amogh - thanks for that my friend...it worked. I missed that detail. Please can you put this as an answer / I would like to accept this as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said `Command` in Action parameter is an Enum:

```
public enum Command { SaveAndAddMore, SaveAndNext, Save, Delete }
```

So whatever values given to button is need to be same as Emum values, So your first button which is working having value same as Enum value i.e. `SaveAndAddMore`. Changing value of second button to `SaveAndNext` will work as you expected. So your div after change will be:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="SaveAndAddMore" name="command" class="btn btn-default" />
            <input type="submit" value="SaveAndNext" name="command" class="btn" />

        </div>
    </div>
```